# Find out all useful columns in a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which has 50+ columns but only few columns are getting used. that means when any stored procedure uses that table it only refers 4-5 columns in select/where statements . rest of columns are not getting used . i just want to list down those columns that are actually getting used. one way is finding out the dependencies of a table and then go through every SP and find out which columns are getting used . but in that case i have around 30+ Sp. is there any efficient way to do it.

Comment: I'd look for it in the dictionary, can't remember... column use(d) something.

Comment: by useful columns in a table i mean that some stored procedure is referring those columns . if in my db no sp is referring a particular column in a table then that column is not useful for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name from syscomments c 
join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id 
where TEXT like '%table_name%' and TEXT like '%column_name%'
```

In table_name give you table name, in column_name give the column for which you want to chck the procedure dependencies.You will get the stored procedure names as output

Comment: Thank you very much . this will do .

Answer (score 3):

To use multiple columns in a procedure, you can use a code like below

```
create procedure sp_sample
@column_names varchar(200)
as
if @column_names='' or @column_nams is null
  set @column_names='*'

exec ('select '+@column_name +' from table')
```

Here are some examples :

```
exec sp_sample @columnname='id,name'
```

or

```
exec sp_sample @columnname='id,name,telphone'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import your database as a database project using the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh272686), you will be able to find all references to a table or column using the "Find All References" context command. What makes this particularly useful is the accuracy: it will even find instances of `SELECT *` that don't mention the column explicitly, but implicitly refer to it anyway. It will also not be confused by tables or columns with similar names (finding particular instances of `ID` is otherwise rather problematic).

If all you want to know if a column is referenced at all, you can simply delete it and see if any "unresolved reference" errors appear in the error list -- if yes, then the column is used somewhere.